# Proving Sin Cos Tan

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am asked to prove the following: $$\dfrac{1-\cos x}{\sin x}=\dfrac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}=\tan\dfrac x2.$$

Looking at the answer 
[image]

I am not able to see what is going on here:

$$\frac{1 - \cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{1 - \cos{(2\cdot\frac{x}{2})}}{\sin{(2\cdot\frac{x}{2})}}.$$

Comment: The step I think you're referring to is just writing $$x = 2 \cdot \frac{x}{2}$$ and then taking sine / cosine across this equality.

Comment: Yes, you're confusing $\sin 2x$ with $\sin^2 x$.

Comment: hffff.how am i not able to see that. So stupid, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have mistaken $\cos(2x)$ with $\cos^2 x$. In the step you seem to be referring to, they write

$$x = 2 \cdot \frac x 2$$

and then take cosine / sine across the equality to get

$$\cos x = \cos \left(2 \frac x 2 \right) \quad\quad \sin x = \sin \left(2 \frac x 2 \right)$$

They then proceed with double-angle identities.